# ASP.Net WebForms Model Binding GridView Using Entity Framework 5.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, model-binding

im binding `List<T>` to my `GridView` where `T` is the object created by `EntityFramework` from my database. There is a foreign key in my said table and i want to display its corresponding text value in the GridView.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Foreign Key Type">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="LabelID" Visible="true"  runat="server"
                         Text="<%# Item.<foreignKeyTable>.Text %>"  >
              </asp:Label>                                               
          </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

when i do that i get the following error

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

how can i get pass that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have query code that does the following:

```
using (var ctx = new SomeContext())
{
   var data = ctx.Data.Where(..).ToList();
   return data;
}
```

You may not have a using, but either way, the context has it's Dispose() method on it, and any unloaded navigation properties will always fail, because there is no context alive for it to attach to.  Even though you may use the context within a method, and may not be storing it globally, as long as you aren't explicitly disposing the context, by calling the method or with a using statement, you will be fine.

Comment: i was using the `GenericRepo` get all function, now i overrided it in the concrete repo and used `Include` to eager load the related entity... tnx for your input